# While Loop Continues Despite Condition Being Met

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hey everyone so I've been trying to write what should be a really easy counting program for my CS class, but for some reason it keeps spitting back out the "Please enter a number (0 to stop): " prompt and seems to completely disregard the while loop. If the condition inside the while loop is being met, why does the while loop not stop even if 0 is entered? I have done C# in the past, but I'm not really familiar with Java's caveats, so if there's anything weird that Java doesn't like me to do let me know. For a more detailed description of the program, it's supposed to read both negative and positive numbers from the user, output the sum of the negatives and the positives individually, and then take the average. (Obviously below is just the problematic piece of code.)

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double average;
    double numPositive=0.0;
    double numNegative=0.0;
    double input = 0.0;
    do 
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number (0 to stop): ");
            input = scanner.nextDouble();   
        if (input < 0.0)
        {
            numNegative += scanner.nextDouble();

        }
        else if (input > 0.0)
        {
            numPositive += scanner.nextDouble();

        }

    } while (Math.abs(input) > 1.0e-6);  // make the tolerance whatever you want.
```

Comment: One advice: if at some point you think "the program does not follow the logic OR I made some mistake implementing the logic", the latter answer is usually the right one.

Answer (score 7):

You never change `input` after the initial assignment; the loop will continue on forever. I think you forgot to call `scanner.nextDouble()` again.

Comment: DavisB's answer is better; if he added another `scanner.nextDouble` then only odd inputs would act as a control of the loop and even inputs would be processed, which would be rather weird/complex.

Answer (score 5):

You're not taking in `input` after initially retrieving it.

Your `scanner.nextDouble()` assigns to `numNegative` and `numPositive`- neither of which is checked by the `while` loop.

```
while (input != 0.0)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number (0 to stop): ");
        input = scanner.nextDouble();

        if (input < 0.0)
        {
            numNegative += input;

        }
        else if (input > 0.0)
        {
            numPositive += input;

        }

    }
```

Comment: @duffymo Go for it. You have my express permission to edit my post.

Comment: I don't need permission; it's the motivation that escapes me.

Comment: @duffymo I know, it's a resounding meh.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning a value to `input` anywhere inside your loop. So, the initial value remains, and the loop won't exit.